# parsing XML file for add marker on google-map application

Tags: android, google-maps, xml-parsing, google-maps-markers

i have a problem for adding a marker from XML file

this my XML file

```
<PA>
<node>
    <id>1</id>
    <nama>SMP 8  Cimahi</nama>
    <longitude>-6.894581</longitude>
    <latitude>107.536519</latitude>
    <kategori>sekolah</kategori>
</node>
```

i want to parse value of longitude and latitude with DOM parser

this a piece of my code on activity file

```
 try {

         DocumentBuilderFactory DBF;
            DocumentBuilder DB;
            Document dom;
            Element elt;

            DBF = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DB = DBF.newDocumentBuilder();
            dom = DB.parse(new InputSource(getAssets().open("database.xml")));
            elt = dom.getDocumentElement(); 

        NodeList nodeList = elt.getElementsByTagName("node");
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

            Node node = nodeList.item(i);

            Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                            NodeList longList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("longitude");
            Element longElement = (Element) longList.item(0);
            longList = longElement.getChildNodes();

            int lng = ((int) (Double.parseDouble(longList.item(0).getNodeValue()) *1E6));


            NodeList latList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("latitude");
            Element latElement = (Element) latList.item(0);
            latList = latElement.getChildNodes();

            int lat = ((int) (Double.parseDouble(latList.item(0).getNodeValue()) *1E6));

            List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
            Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.school);
            markerpeta itemizedoverlay = new markerpeta(drawable,this);

            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat,lng);
            OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "", null);

            itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
            mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
```

this my markerpeta class

```
public class markerpeta extends ItemizedOverlay {
private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlay = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
private Context mContext;
//private peta peta;

public markerpeta(Drawable defaultMarker) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public markerpeta(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    mContext = context;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay){
    mOverlay.add(overlay);
    populate();

}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mOverlay.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mOverlay.size();
}

 @Override
        protected boolean onTap(int index) {
          OverlayItem item = mOverlay.get(index);
          AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
          dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
          dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
          dialog.setPositiveButton("Close", new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    arg0.dismiss();
             }
            });
          dialog.show();
          return true;
        }
```

}

there's no error in this code, but there's no marker on the application, anyone can help me?
thank you

Comment: can you paste the code for the markerpeta class

Answer (score 0):

In your markerpeta class add the below the method

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);           
}
```

also replace the below two lines an try

```
Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.school);
markerpeta itemizedoverlay = new markerpeta(drawable,this);
```

with

Drawable drawable =getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.school);
  markerpeta itemizedoverlay = new markerpeta(drawable,getApplicationContext());

Comment: populate() change it to this.populate();

Comment: still not working @DilSe , i think the problem is not on the marker, but in the parsing the XML file to take the longitude and latitude value, because if use ordinary point it's work normal and the marker is appears

Comment: ok, i think the problem is on parsing XML file to take the longitude and latitude value

Comment: can you give me your email?so i can send my project to you?, please help me